# Filtering out non-intentional stories in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an easy way to filter out "Non-Intentional" stories from the Facebook Graph API.  For instance, when I check a user's feed I get tons of "John Smith is now friends with xyz" posts, which are not actually posted by a user.

The graph API used to not return these at all.  For older Facebook apps, there is a migration setting "Include recent activity stories" which suppressed these, but new apps don't get that migration option.

I've resorted to a RegEx and checking for a "story_tags" attribute, but I was hoping there's a cleaner way (maybe a query flag to the /feed endpoint?)

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score -2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

posts

The user's own posts.

Any valid access_token or read_stream to see non-public posts.

array of Post objects.

I think this is it.

Comment: no, unintentional stories still show up for me using the "post" endpoint